# MVC4 WebApplication - global variables available in views (cshtml files) using Razor engine

Tags: internationalization, resources, asp.net-mvc-4, view, global-variables

I wonder how it is now possible, using MVC4, to get such functionality which was possible in MVC3, to declare some variables (and/or constraints) which are then available in all cshtml files. I used this to make language files.

Earlier (in MVC3) I had `App_Code` folder in my Solution, where I put the file Lang.cshtml. In this file (valid resource for me) I had e.g.

```
@functions{
    public static readonly string G_ADD = "Dodaj";
    public static readonly string G_CREATE = "Utwórz";
    public static readonly string G_SAVE = "Zapisz";
    public static readonly string G_EDIT = "Edytuj";
    public static readonly string G_DETAILS = "Szczegóły";
    public static readonly string G_DELETE = "Usuń";
    public static readonly string G_SEARCH = "Szukaj";
    public static readonly string G_FIRST = "<< Pierwsza";
    public static readonly string G_LAST = "Ostatnia >>";
    public static readonly string G_PREV = "< Poprzednia";
    public static readonly string G_NEXT = "Następna >";
    public static readonly string G_ACTION = "Akcja";
    public static readonly string G_ID = "ID";
    public static readonly string G_PAGE = "STRONA";
    public static readonly string G_OF = "z";
    public static readonly string G_FROM = "z";
    public static readonly string G_TO = "do";
    public static readonly string G_ALL = "-- Wszystkie";
    public static readonly string G_RECORDS = "Rekordów:";
    public static readonly string G_CHOOSE = "Wybierz:";
    public static readonly string G_BACK = "Wróć";
    public static readonly string G_VIEW_CHART = "Wyświetl wykres";
}
```

so I could use the strings in any .cshtml (View) e.g.
`@Lang.G_ADD` 
or even
`@Html.ActionLink(@Lang.G_ADD, "AddContract", new { id = item.CONTRACT_ID });`

Especially it makes my app more user-friendly for all those people working on i18n of it.
Now this solution doesn't work in MVC4 :/

The available resources solution is not much-effective. Imagine, that everytime you need to write `AppName.Properties.Resources.G_ADD`.

Also the XML in the Resources.resx looks baaaaaaadly. Very.

Writting any method to enumerate the Resources still do the job partially only as it is bloating the code and I am following "less the code the better" idea.

Please point me to the right direction. Also any ready solution is appreciated :)

Thank You all in advance!

Comment: If you and your localizers use the resource editor built into Visual Studio, then neither you nor they have to interact with the generated XML directly.  Is this your biggest concern about using Resource files for localization?

Comment: The idea was not-to-give anyone except dev-team access to sources or IDEs (property, licensing, training, such stuff). The .cshtml file could be (almost) plain text file which is easier to manipulate even for non-skilled team of translators but ok, thank you for the idea, I already messed with the XML and provided i18n-team simple XML web-editor so they could contribute on-the-fly :)